# Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I this function was working but I guess one or the other library updated I'm getting this error. This function I took from [this](https://perslab.github.io/bentsen-rausch-2020/15_tany_wgcna_pseudo.html) to get hubgenes from the network.

```
> hubgenes <- lapply(seq_len(length(Network)), function(x) {
+   dat <- modulekME[Network[[x]], ]
+   dat <- dat[order(-dat[paste0("kME", names(Network)[x])]), ]
+   gene <- rownames(dat)
+   return(gene)
+ })
Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

Any suggestions how to workaround or fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be caused by this line:

```
dat<-dat[order(-dat[paste0("kME",names(Network)[x])]),]
```

The outer indexing is fine, but the row ordering is done by

```
order(-dat[paste0("kME",names(Network)[x])])
```

It looks as though you are trying to order by a column whose name is constructed by

```
paste0("kME",names(Network)[x])
```

but your code to do that is wrong.  If that's what you are trying to do, you should write it as

```
order(-dat[[paste0("kME",names(Network)[x])]])
```

or (if `dat` is a matrix or dataframe, but not a tibble):

```
order(-dat[, paste0("kME",names(Network)[x])])
```

I'd use the first option, because it works for tibbles too. (The first option doesn't work for matrices, but I think those are less likely here.)  I'd also suggest using some intermediate variables so your code is easier to read.  Then your calculation could be rewritten as

```
hubgenes<-lapply(seq_len(length(Network)), function(x) {
  dat <- modulekME[Network[[x]], ]
  colname <- paste0("kME", names(Network)[x])
  o <- order(-dat[[colname]])
  dat <- dat[o, ]
  rownames(dat)
})
```

Comment: this worked and thank for the detailed explanation of the function which i took from one of the paper code

Answer (score 2):

You did

```
> mtcars[order(-mtcars[1:3])]
Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

what you want is

```
> mtcars[do.call(order, c(mtcars[, 1:3], decreasing=TRUE)), ]
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
...
```

*Explanation:* `order()` expects *"a sequence of numeric, complex, character or logical vectors"* as first argument but you provided a `"data.frame"`. To get the order subsequently for selected columns we may use `do.call` as explained in `?order`. Setting `-` for negative order won't work, but we can pass the `decreasing=TRUE` by simply `c`oncatenating it to the data.

Comment: I will try this, as a matter of fact it was working fine which i have used earlier .not sure what changed the only thing i did is update some library